# how to run node js remotely

Tags: node.js, putty, remote-access

I am running node using putty. but it doesn't work when putty session expire. How can I start node js permanently, should not be terminated if putty session end.

Answer (score 20):

I just solved that issue yesterday using Forever > http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever

It's awesome.

1. For Installing: `npm install Forver`
2. For running: `forever start yourServer.js`
3. For checking if its running: `forever list`

cool eh?

Comment: Nice! Looks like it can be used for any process, not just node.js.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you use a deamon to keep it running. A proper answer depends on what type of OS your remote machine is running (windows ?).

It's  best to run node.js on *unix.

Answer (score 3):

Among what Raynos and nEEbz are suggesting you can also try to use [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). This is very handy especially if you are using putty to connect to remote server. Check out [this](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) screen tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and gentle introduction to "screen" .

In ubuntu, if you need to install it, use: apt-get install screen

First use:

```
$ screen
```

bunch of stuff prints out, then another shell prompt

$ node ./myapp.js

now your node app is running

You want to edit some other code?

control-a c

the window clears, and you now have another shell prompt. node is still running....

$ edit public/somewebfile.html

save it, still in editor
go back to node

> control-a control-a

screen switches back to the screen running node

need to leave the office for a few minutes

```
control-a control-d
(screen detaches from your location... processes remain attached)
$ logout
```

screen disconnects, but nodejs and the editor are still running...

back at home... want to connect to work

```
> ssh work.some.where
> screen -D -R
screen reconnecting....
```

now you see the nodejs shell screen again, or control-a control-a to switch back to that editor

control-a ? shows available commands, or read the nice man page: man screen

Answer (score 2):

You can also run nohup:

```
nohup node app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error when you do `npm install Forever`, do `npm install forever -g`

I got that problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Answer (score 0):

Use `PM2`

just install `pm2` on the server and run app like this : `pm2 start app.js`

you can also monitor your application from the web panel

[PM2 (proccess manager)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)